# append parentheses to a combination of alphabetic and japanese strings in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some data that looks like this in a dataframe:

```
Japanese
--------
明日|Adverb の 天気|Weather は なんですか
```

Here, 明日 is labeled with Adverb and 天気 is labeled with Weather.

Using Pandas and regex, I am looking for a way to append `{}` around the characters that have Japanese, the pipe, and English, but not around the Japanese only.
I've tried using regex with the following but keep getting a syntax error:

> df.['Japanese'] = df['Japanese'].str.append('(.+?\|[A-Za-z_]+)\',
>   '{(.+?\|[A-Za-z_]+)}')

The desired output is as follows (also looking for a way to remove all spaces at the same time...if this isn't possible i can do that afterwards):

```
Japanese
--------
{明日|Adverb}の{天気|Weather}はなんですか
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['Japanese'] = df['Japanese'].str.replace(r'(\w*\|[a-zA-Z]+)', r'{\1}', regex=True)   

# To remove white space use
df.Japanese.str.replace('\s',"", regex=True, inplace=True) 

# Output:

0    {'明日|Adverb'}の{'天気|Weather'}はなんですか
Name: Japanese, dtype: object
```

Comment: @user_seaweed I've updated the regex. Can you check if it works?

Comment: @user_seaweed Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this

```
df['Japanese'].replace(r'(.+?\|[A-Za-z_]+)','{\g<0>}', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

`\g<0>` is a reference to the group inside the `(` and `)`

unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to replace spaces in one line so after that you want to do

```
df['Japanese'].replace('\s','', inplace=True,regex=True)
```

Comment: that worked, except it's also grabbing spaces, e.g., {の 天気|Weather}